# How can I maintain line breaks in body text with mailx when sending attachments?

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, quoting

I have a script that emails the text of a log file as the body of the email.  That log file has some blank lines between lines of text for readability.

When I use the following line in the script, the email sends fine with proper formatting:

```
cat ${log}|mailx -s "Email Subject Line" ${i} < ${log}
```

However, I now want to attached several files to the email.  I modified the line to this:

```
( echo `cat ${log}` ; uuencode ${file1} ${file1a} ; uuencode ${file2} ${file2a} ; uuencode ${file3} ${file3a} ) | mailx -m -s "Email Subject Line" ${i}
```

Note that `${i}` is the email recipient in both lines.

So, now the email sends fine with the attachments, but the body of the message is just one big block of text with no line breaks or anything.

Did I not write the mailx line correctly?  Is there a way I can get the formatting to persist into the body of the message?

Comment: What version/incarnation of mailx are you using?

Comment: Loosely related: [How can I make the bash backtick operator keep newlines in output?](http://superuser.com/q/403800/354511)

Answer (score 1):

Unquoted newlines in command lines get treated as spaces;
that's why you can say things like

```
command1  &&
command2
```

Well, sometimes unquoted newlines get treated like semicolons. 
But, when you say

```
echo `cat ${log}`
```

all the newlines in the log file get turned into spaces. 
You could fix this by saying

```
echo "`cat ${log}`"
```

but why not just say

```
cat ${log}
```

?

Comment: Thank you for the response! Adding double quotes fixed it.  Removing the back ticks didn't work. I had tried that before and it just prints the file path of the log as the body of the email. But the double quotes did it! Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to provide a solution that helped you, but … are you sure you copied my last command exactly? I didn't say `echo ${log}` or `echo cat ${log}` (which is what you wrote in the first version of your question). I said `cat ${log}`, with ***no*** `echo`. (Although I would actually advise `cat "${log}"`, to be safer. You should always quote shell variables unless you have a good reason not to, and you're *sure* you know what you're doing. By contrast, while braces can be important, they're not as important as quotes, so `cat "$log"` is good enough. Similarly, `"$file1"`, etc.)